# How to declare a console log in a javascript if condition function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, payment

i am using a pop payment gate of paylike so i redirect the user to a new page to make payment where the pop up will be display.

in the paylike docs it says that if the popup is close the value is "closed"

I want to try and use that close value in a if condition statement to redirect the user back to previous request.

here is the action function code

```
function( err, res ){
            if (err)
                return console.log(err);

        console.log(res.transaction.id);

        var txn = res.transaction.id;

        var action = consolde.log(err);

        // if console log is Closed redirect back to preview
        if(action = 'closed') {

            //Redirect to preview page
        }
```

Please help me out.

if the pop up is close the console.log(err) return "closed" in the inspected element.

Comment: `if(action = 'closed')` is an assignment, try `if(action == 'closed')` for equality

Comment: some funny looking PHP you got there ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some changes:

```
var action= err; 
if(action == 'closed'){

}
```

Also, I think you have to return err and not console.log(err) or check it before enter in this function:

```
if (err)
    return err;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison logic is incorrect.

It should be like:

```
if(action == 'closed') {
    console.log('Your stuffs');
    //Redirect to preview page
}
else {
console.log('Failed : Your stuffs');
}
```